# bokeh chart download as csv

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I've got a Bokeh app that charts multiple lines depending on the values for certain widgets that a user selects. I would like to give the user the opportunity to download the raw data behind the chart.

Is it possible to download the data for certain lines shown in a Bokeh chart as a csv/Excel file?

**Edit:**

As suggested, I have included the CustomJS callback from this Git repo in my script:
https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/export_csv

Since my Bokeh source contains data for a `Multiline` chart and not a `DataTable` the output is not as expected. Unfortunately, I don't have any experience with Javascript. How can I modify the script such that the returned csv file accurately shows the data stored in my source multilines `xs` and `ys`?

Comment: The answers on this question might be able to help solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388511/send-file-from-server-to-client-on-bokeh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an example in the repo that has a simple `CustomJS` callback that will allow the user to download the CDS contents as a CSV:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/app/export_csv

Comment: Thank you for the guidance - I was able to include the CustomJS callback from the linked repo in my script. However, the csv output is not as expected. I assume because my Bokeh source contains data for a Multiline chart  and not a DataTable.

Comment: Right, the columns for `MultiLine` glyphs are "lists of lists". You will need to extract just the sub-parts you want to export.

Comment: The link is broken, this works: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/branch-3.3/examples/server/app/export_csv

Comment: Is there also a way to download the data as an xlsx format? What would I need to change in the Java Script?